# Who creates uniform trial court & supplementary rules?

Tags: united-states, rules-of-court, authority

States and counties in the U.S.A. can have court rules, such as:

- [New York State's Administrative Rules of the Unified Court System & Uniform Rules of the Trial Courts](http://ww2.nycourts.gov/rules/index.shtml)
- [Oregon's Uniform Trial Court Rules](https://www.courts.oregon.gov/programs/utcr/Pages/currentrules.aspx) and [Supplementary Local Rules](https://www.courts.oregon.gov/rules/Pages/slr.aspx)
- [Georgia's Court Rules](https://www.gasupreme.us/rules/) (including uniform rules)
- [Louisiana's Court Rules](https://www.lasc.org/Court_Rules)

Who sets these rules? If it's not the legislature, by what authority?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most US states such rules are set by the state's highest court, often but not always known as the State Supreme Court. The legislature could set such rules, but normally does not. It may authorize the court to do so.

Mote that the Oregon rules (on a [page](https://www.courts.oregon.gov/programs/utcr/committee/Pages/default.aspx) easy to reach for the one linked above) say:

> Proposed changes to the Uniform Trial Court Rules (UTCR) and Supplementary Local Rules (SLR) are reviewed annually by the UTCR Committee.  The committee makes recommendations to approve, disapprove or modify these proposals.  After considering these recommendations, the Chief Justice or the entire Supreme Court, reaches a final decision on whether to approve or disapprove a proposed change.

The [Georgia rules](https://www.gasupreme.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/UNIFORM-SUPERIOR-COURT-RULES-2022_03_03.pdf) state:

> **Rule 1. PREAMBLE **-
> Pursuant to the inherent powers of the Court and Article VI, Section IX, Paragraph I of the Georgia Constitution of 1983, and in order to provide for the speedy, efficient and inexpensive resolution of disputes and prosecutions, these rules are promulgated.

> **Rule 1.6**
> The Council of Superior Court Judges shall have a permanent committee to **recommend to the Supreme Court** such changes and additions to these rules as may from time to time appear necessary or desirable. [*Emphasis added*]

Many other states have somewhat similar procedures. Others including NY and California, set more of the rules by statute.

On the Federal level, the various Federal Rules of Procedure (Civil, Criminal, and Supreme Court, perhaps others) are set by the Supreme Court, although they are usually drafted by an <s>ABA committee</s> Court appointed advisory committee and submitted to the Court for approval, I understand.  Many (but not all) state rules closely imitate the Federal rules, down to the numbering and wording in many cases.

Comment: Two important exceptions are New York State and California which both include far more of their court rules in statutes than is typical. At the federal level, they are proposed by a SCOTUS appointed advisory committee not an ABA committee. Most state supreme court likewise appoint advisory committees to draft in the first iinstance.

Comment: @ohwilleke Thanks I have made corrections based on your comments